# Alternative to browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, rhel

I am working on the requirement where I need to get the current URL accessed by user in browser.

I have two approaches right now:

1. **Read url from the browser specific database history:** but problem with this approach is that it does not give the correct URL. It give the last accessed URL but not the URL on which user is currently working.
2. **Other option is user extensions in browser itself**, and capture the url on tab change event of browser. This approach works fine but here I need to ask user for adding extension to the browser.

I want to know some other approach if any?
Can I achieve the same by running some program of javascript at specific interval of time to capture the URL?

Platfrom I am working on is : RedHat (RHEL)
Browser: firefox and Chrome.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get on which URL the user is on **your** website or on **any** website?

Comment: @pschichtel I am looking for Any website URL.

Comment: Going with browser extension is the best way.